# Android Volley request not updating

Tags: java, android, android-studio, server, android-volley

I have a simple database/server setup that so far is working fine. And I have an app where I'm testing out how Volley works. 
Basically, I have a database of "users" where each JSON object has a unique ID, username, email, and password.
I have a Volley function called updateUser `upUser` that takes the ID number for that person, as well as a new username. This function just changes the username for that user. So if I have `ID: 5, User: test`, and I type in my address bar: `"stringServerURL:8080/upUser/5/newTEST"`, it'll change the username for ID# 5 from `test` to `newTEST`. Works as intended so far.

From the android side, I have a method

```
public void updateRecords(volleyHttpRequest r, String info, int id){

        final volleyHttpRequest req = r;
        final String str = info;
        final int num = id;

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                req.makearequest("http://some-server-address:8080/upUser/" + num + "/" + str);
            }
        });

       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The `volleyHttpRequest r` parameter is:

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getApplicationContext());
final volleyHttpRequest request = new volleyHttpRequest(pDialog,0);
```

and the `makearequest()` method is:

```
public void  makearequest(String url) {
        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        });
        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

So it doesn't crash or anything, and it seems to work, but when I pass in 5 for `num` and "newTEST" for `str`, nothing gets updated. I tried following the online tutorials as closely as possible, but it only works if I update it directly from the address bar.

I did find this in the "Log":

```
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea072a00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd690b5e0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea072a00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd690b5e0)
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0xd602b680 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xd69882a0
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
    getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea072a00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd690b5e0)
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xea072a00: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd690b5e0)
```

I think it has something to do with the inactive input connection, but the server is running and I have no idea where to look.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime volley save data in cache and give the same data many time you should first clear volley cache and then call data.

First use this to clear volley cache..

```
    Volley.newRequestQueue(context).getCache().clear();
```